# Evil Emacs: is there a way to disable vim-like keys in «insert» mode?

Tags: plugins, emacs, configuration, editor, elisp

I like VIM idea of text objects, so I installed [EVIL](http://www.emacswiki.org/Evil) *(a Emacs plugin to emulate VIM features)*. But I'd like «insert» mode to leave Emacs keybindings unchanged *(except perhaps <kbd>Escape</kbd> which is to switch into «normal» mode)*. Any way to achieve this?

By the way: ATM «insert» mode have a mixed set of hotkeys, which isn't very comfortable either way. E.g. the «M-b» works as in Emacs, but the «C-o» works as in VIM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the *#emacs* IRC channel I was told that [someone already solved a similar problem](https://gist.github.com/kidd/1828878). Here's the modified version I use:

```
(require 'evil)
;; remove all keybindings from insert-state keymap
(setcdr evil-insert-state-map nil)
;; but [escape] should switch back to normal state
(define-key evil-insert-state-map [escape] 'evil-normal-state)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-u") 'evil-scroll-up)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "[ m") 'beginning-of-defun)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "] m") 'end-of-defun)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "k") 'evil-previous-visual-line)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "j") 'evil-next-visual-line)

(evil-mode t)
(setq evil-jumps-cross-buffers nil) ;; for C-o and C-i to not cross buffers
(provide 'emvil)
```

The `(provide 'emvil)` is to allow `require '`ing it in the configuration. I also found it useful to jump-to-definition in the next split screen unless the definition is in the buffer I'm currently in. Here's the code:

```
(defun evil-goto-definition-next-split ()
    "If there's a free split, goto definition in this split,
    otherwise use current one (except when a definition in the
    current split)"
    (interactive)
    (let ((origin-spl (selected-window))
          (origin-buf (current-buffer)))
      (evil-goto-definition)
      (when (and (eq origin-spl (selected-window)) ;; otherwise it's done
                 (not (eq origin-buf (current-buffer)))) ;; otherwise either definition not found, or
                                                         ;; it's in the same buffer
        (let ((defin-buf (current-buffer))
              (defin-point (point)))
          (switch-to-buffer origin-buf)
          (other-window 1)
          (switch-to-buffer defin-buf)
          (goto-char defin-point)
          ))
      ))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "g d") 'evil-goto-definition-next-split)
```

Comment: Hm, I got it. Sometimes *(I can't yet tell on what is it depends)* the EVIL changes list in the variable «global-map». Hm…

Comment: Ah, I got it. The `(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "<ESC>") 'evil-normal-state)` somehow brokes all a keybindings, although should only touch the Escape key.

Comment: I finally found… I have no idea what the difference, but the only works is `(define-key evil-insert-state-map [escape] 'evil-normal-state)
`

Comment: Just if anybody curious, I have at the present moment this in my Emacs: `(evil-mode)  
(setq evil-insert-state-map global-map)  
(define-key evil-insert-state-map [escape] 'evil-normal-state)  
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-z") 'undo-tree-redo)`

Comment: There is some new property set: evil-disable-insert-state-bindings  But can't find the way to enable it

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will mess up evil's mechanism for recording macros.